# 画像URLスクレイピング

Tags: ruby

Ruby で画像URLをスクレイピングしたいです。

```
<div> 
<a href="URL" titile="xxx"> 
<img alt="yyy" src="ここのURLをクスレイピングしたいです> 
</a>
```

以下のように記述しました。

```
require 'mechanize'

agent= Mechanize.new 
page = agent.get("取得したいサイトURL") 
elements = page.search('a img')

elements.each do |ele| 
    puts ele.get_attribute('src') 
end
```

そして、`ruby scraping_image.rb`をターミナルに記載しENZTERキーを押したのですが、ターミナルにただ大きな空欄が出来るだけで、何も欲しい情報が得られませんでした。
エラーメッセージ等は表示されませんでした。

違うタグを取得するように記述するべきだったでしょうか？ 
お願いします。

Comment: 何か失敗したので質問なさっているのだと思います。どういう失敗なのか（思い通りいかなかった点）を質問に含めると回答が得られ易いです。エラーになった場合はエラーメッセージも。

Comment: ruby scraping_image.rbをターミナルに記載しENZTERキーを押した後、ターミナルにただ大きな空欄が出来るだけで、何も欲しい情報が得られませんでした。
エラーメッセージ等は表示されませんでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問のコードは私の手元でも動きました。間違いは無さそうです。
下記のように`src`属性だけでなく、要素ごと出力して様子を見るとよいでしょう。

```
puts ele
puts ele.get_attribute('src')
```

問題があるとすれば、取得しているWebページの構造です。
「`a`タグの下に`img`タグがあり、それが`src`属性を持っている」というのが想定する構造ですが、そうはなっていないのでしょう。
「空欄」が出力されたという事は`img`タグは発見されているが、それに`src`属性が無いか`src`の値が空文字やスペースなのだろうと推測します。

Comment: できました、ありがとうございました！元のコードのままでできました。
最初なぜ空欄しか出なかったのかとても疑問です。。。